# Firebase Admin SDK: list_users() error INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm using the [Firebase Admin Python SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python) to connect to our Firebase instance where are users are stored for a web application. I am attempting to create a job that queries Firebase every day and gets a count of users and then archives this off to our data warehouse to report on it going forward. I've successfully [created service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#creating_a_service_account) and made sure the credentials are valid by accessing the Google Cloud Platform (following [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)):

```
import firebase_admin

creds = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate("/Users/me/Downloads/service-account-146c01507e2b.json")
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(creds)
```

However, the instructions are not clear on how I go about authenticating in order to pull back a [list of all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users). It just says to import the `auth` class and then run `auth.list_users()` but doesn't clarify how to authenticate using this class.

When I run `firebase_admin.auth.list_users()` I get the following error: `InvalidArgumentError: Error while calling Auth service (INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION).`

Can anyone help me understand how/where I authenticate with my service account credentials? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Firebase Service Account

The Firebase service account should be generated from:

**Firebase Console > Project Settings > Service Accounts** and clicking <kbd>**Generate new private key**</kbd>

### Initialize Firebase SDK

```
import json
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials


FIREBASE_CERT = "credentials/firebase-adminsdk-####-##########.json"

with open(FIREBASE_CERT) as json_file:
  json_data = json.load(json_file)

DEFAULT_CRED = credentials.Certificate(json_data)

app_instance = firebase_admin.initialize_app(DEFAULT_CRED)

firebase_admin.auth.list_users()
```

Comment: When I replaced `FIREBASE_CERT` with my credentials and ran the script I got this error: `InvalidArgumentError: Error while calling Auth service (INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSION).`. Do I need to be passing specific arguments to the `list_users()` function? Or do I not have the correct permissions with my service account credentials? I checked the `app_instance` variable and I successfully initialized it.

Comment: I feel like we initialize the `app_instance` variable and then don't reference it when asking for the users, is that why it's throwing an error?

Comment: I generated the service account credentials via Google Cloud Platform > APIs & Services > Credentials > Create Credentials. Where they tell me to create it https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#creating_a_service_account. I created the `app_instance` variable and can run `print app_instance.project_id` and see that I'm connected to the correct Firebase instance. Doesn't that mean I have the correct permissions? However, we disregard that `app_instance` variable and then run `firebase_admin.auth.list_users()` and I get the permission error.

Comment: Try generating a new private key through the Firebase Console for your project. https://console.firebase.google.com

Comment: It worked when I generated the credentials via the Firebase Console, as opposed to the Google Cloud Platform console.